# Methods to handle an arbitrary peak within a distribution

Tags: distributions, zero-inflation

I had someone come to me for advice on how to deal with their weird data. The predictor variable is categorical (experimental condition), and the outcome variable is continuous (amount of money in a savings account during the experimental period). This should just be a simple ANOVA or linear regression. The problem is, the outcome variable has a huge peak at \$5000 - because above \$5000, there's no added interest for money in the account, so there's no real benefit for keeping it there.

I advised them to run the analyses and look at the residuals to see just how bad the problem really is, and to also see if their intervention was differentially effective on people at or near the \$5000 cutoff by testing an interaction between intervention condition and baseline amount. Alternatively, I suggested they could cut out anybody who's already at 5k at the start, but this risks omitting a pretty big amount of the sample. And transformation doesn't instinctively feel likely to solve this issue given it's a single peak.

Ultimately, none of those feel like good answers. Is there something like a zero-inflated model that would work for this, except  the inflation isn't at 0 but at 5000? Or is there an alternative strategy I could suggest?

Comment: Consider treating this as a censored regression model: treat all outcomes of \$5000 or greater as being indefinite.